# Array of array of string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am doing one task and I need to find shortest path on graph.
There are no problems at all with algorithm. The problem is how to output paths from source to all other vertexes. Edges has names too, not only weights. How should I initialize matrix of strings correctly? Is it possible at all?

I want this code work:

```
printf(" -(%s)-> %d", names[prev][next], mas[j]);
```

`mas[j]` is array with vertexes
`names` - array of arrays of `string`

I am trying to initialize matrix this way:

```
 string  names[N][N] = {
         {'0', 'A', '0', 'B', 'E', '0', '0', 'P1', '0'},
         {'A', '0', 'D', 'I', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
         {'0', 'D', '0', '0', '0', 'H', 'F', '0', '0'},
         {'B', 'I', '0', '0', '0', 'H', '0', '0', '0'},
         {'E', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P2', '0'},
         {'0', '0', 'H', 'H', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P4'},
          {'0', '0', 'F', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'P3'},
         {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
          {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
 };
```

My programm: http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE

Comment: So, C or C++? You can't eat your lunch and have your lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong quotes for string literals. Single quotes `'` are used for character literals, and in fact `'P1'` is a multi-character literal (which I'm certain you don't even want to mess with). Instead, use double quotes `"` around your literals.

The reason they all need to be string literals is because there is no `std::string` constructor that takes only a `char`. There is, however, a constructor that takes a C-style string (as created by a string literal).

Note that `printf` will expect a C-style string, so you'll need to do `names[prev][next].c_str()`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. When I try to init matrix ideone says: `prog.cpp:25: error: variable-sized object 'names' may not be initialized`? What's wrong? http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You need to change *all* of the literals to double quotes. I'll explain why in an edit. You should also make `N` `const` so that you're not using a compiler extension for variable length arrays.

Comment: Thx, programm is working now, but not properly. I don't know why, but programm doesn't output anything. `printf(" -(%s)-> %d", names[prev][next].c_str(), mas[j]);` not works. I don't mean this part cause problem. There are no input at all. http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE

Comment: @SharikovVladislav It doesn't print anything at all? Then that branch is not being reached. You need to debug your code to figure out why. That's a whole other task.

Comment: `printf("%s", names[1][1].c_str()); ` shows nothing. Empty output. http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE

Comment: @SharikovVladislav For some reason `printf` isn't working on ideone. `cout` works though. Not sure what's going on there. In fact, if you do a single `cout` at the beginning, the rest of the `printf`s will work.

Comment: Mhm. Much better)  http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE but what is it :) Again and again! Argh!!! It shows some strange codes CXXABI_1.3

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Suggests that you're accessing outside of your array bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am very close to solving this task!  http://ideone.com/ZMiVPE look there. All fine, except paths to N1 and N2 (there are 2 symbols in names for this edges). What's wrong?